Is there a way to play the campaign only and avoid a large download in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered?
So, today I got Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered 50% off to play the campaign. Upon buying it, I get two things in my Steam library: MWR MP and MWR. Now, I started with just the MWR one because I don't care about MP. But the download is 55 GB.
That kind of large download is not really feasible for me at the moment, internet-wise, and I had read beforehand that you can play campaign without the MP, so is there a point in the download when campaign becomes available to just play?
I really don't want to download 38–40 GB of extra content that will be useless to me, given that I only want the story.

That's how the game works. 55GB is the size for SP campaign.
CoD shares their data(such as weapon models, character models, maps that's used in both SP/MP, etc) with MP.
So, technically, the SP data is about 55GB, but the data that's unique to SP is about 25GB or something (judging by recent CoD's data size, MW2 and MW3). So in total it shares about 30GB of the data with MP. So no, you can't just download story and play, you'd need to download them anyway.

PS. you can consider yourself lucky; when this game was released there was no option to download only the single player (at least in PS4, I haven't bought them on Steam since I've played it on PS4).

Oh, I see. I had read somewhere the campaign is playable after either 10.61gb or 16.51gb, on a Steam forum (don't remember now exactly), so I thought I didn't have to get it all to just use that part.

@Nathanman I think that's for PS4. Steam never had such thing, while many other launcher (such as EA app, UBI Connect) has it. You could only play first mission or just tutorial, though.

Okay, just in case anyone finds this in the same search I was doing, I’m writing this.
In Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered on Steam, there is the singleplayer and the multiplayer, both with different AppIDs.
The single player is, in fact, 53.36 GB; I was able to finish its download today.
The reason for the size is that, as mentioned by Skye-AT, the game assets are shared. For example, on SteamDB, both the SP and MP have to download the shared imagefiles depot, making them 33 GB before you add language files and files unique to each mode.
So yes, you have to download 53.36 GB to just play the campaign (which is worth it), and I don’t know, but I imagine the MP is something bigger than the 53 GB for the SP.
